# How to order the result data by the order of values in an Oracle SQL IN() clause

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

When the SQL returns the results, We need to order them in the exact order in which the values were passed to the SQL's `IN()` clause.

**Query and Result: (HR Schema)**

```
select EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME
from EMPLOYEES
where EMPLOYEE_ID in ('151','149','145','147','155');

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME         
----------- --------------------
        145 John                
        147 Alberto             
        149 Eleni               
        151 David               
        155 Oliver
```

But we need them ordered in the order of '151','149','145','147','155'

**Expected Output**

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME         
----------- --------------------
        151 David               
        149 Eleni               
        145 John                
        147 Alberto             
        155 Oliver
```

In MySQL, there is the `FIELD()` function.
How to achieve this in Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can either write your own field function in PL/SQL or use standard SQL's `CASE WHEN`:

```
select EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME
from EMPLOYEES
where EMPLOYEE_ID in ('151','149','145','147','155')
order by case EMPLOYEE_ID 
  when '151' then 1
  when '149' then 2
  when '145' then 3
  when '147' then 4
  when '155' then 5;
```

Here is an alternative with a derived table:

```
select EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME
from EMPLOYEES
join
(
  select '151' as EMPLOYEE_ID, 1 as POS from DUAL
  union all
  select '149' as EMPLOYEE_ID, 2 as POS from DUAL
  union all
  select '145' as EMPLOYEE_ID, 3 as POS from DUAL
  union all
  select '147' as EMPLOYEE_ID, 4 as POS from DUAL
  union all
  select '155' as EMPLOYEE_ID, 5 as POS from DUAL
) IDS ON IDS.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID
order by IDS.POS;
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be building your list with an attribute giving the order and use it in a JOIN with your table.
For example:

```
with yourList(EMPLOYEE_ID, position) as (
    select '151', 1 from dual union all
    select '149', 2 from dual union all
    select '145', 3 from dual union all
    select '147', 4 from dual union all
    select '155', 5 from dual
)
select EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME
from EMPLOYEES inner join yourList using(EMPLOYEE_ID)
order by position;
```

If you want to limit the code to write when your list changes, you can build your list by splitting a string:

```
with yourList(EMPLOYEE_ID, position) as (
    SELECT regexp_substr(stringList, '[^,]+', 1, level), level
      FROM (select '151,149,145,147,155' as stringList from dual)
      CONNECT BY instr(stringList, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
)
select EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME
from EMPLOYEES inner join yourList using(EMPLOYEE_ID)
order by position;
```

In this way you only have to edit your list of IDs, with no other modifications on your query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values in your list are unique

```
select      e.EMPLOYEE_ID,e.FIRST_NAME

from                EMPLOYEES e

            join    (select  rownum as n,column_value as EMPLOYEE_ID 
                     from    table (SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST ('151','149','145','147','155')) t
                    ) t  

            on      t.EMPLOYEE_ID =
                    e.EMPLOYEE_ID

order by    t.n
```

---

```
+-------------+------------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME |
+-------------+------------+
| 151         | David      |
+-------------+------------+
| 149         | Eleni      |
+-------------+------------+
| 145         | John       |
+-------------+------------+
| 147         | Alberto    |
+-------------+------------+
| 155         | Oliver     |
+-------------+------------+
```